# Switch from GCP Cloud Run with Custom Domain and managed certificate to adding a Load Balancer with managed certificate on same domain no downtime

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, devops, load-balancing, google-cloud-run

We have an established GCP Cloud Run instance running the api for fairly high traffic application.

We have a domain mapped to it via "Cloud Run Domain Mappings" with a CNAME pointed to `ghs.googlehosted.com.` and Cloud Run's "Ingress control" is configured to allow all:

[image]

We want to upgrade this system to put it behind a GCP Global External load balancer *at the same subdomain* without downtime.

Google manages the SSL certificates for both.

I don't know how to make this change without downtime.

The problem is that once we create a load balancer, specify the domain for it, and tell Google to create / use a certificate for it, that certificate will never finish installing until, the corresponding DNS record changes are made.

We need to replace our `CNAME` record for that subdomain with an `A` record pointed at the IP address of the load balancer.

But as soon as we make that DNS change, certificate issues are going to be in place until GCP is done verifying/setting up the cert which can take quite a while.

How can we do this without downtime or at least with predictable minimal downtime?

Comment: If you use Google-managed certificates, migrating an existing service to an external Application Load Balancer may incur some downtime, typically less than an hour. This is because the S**SL certificate for your external Application Load Balancer won't be provisioned until you update your DNS records to point to the load balancer’s IP address.**  It may take up to an hour for the SSL certificate to provision and for your domain to begin routing HTTPS traffic to your Cloud Run service. **Refer to similar [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084593), which may help to resolve your issue.**

Comment: Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know if the above comment helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Comment: Hi Henrik, I have converted the comment into a solution for better visibility for community members. Could you please update whether the offered solution and suggested similar [SF link](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084593/how-to-migrate-to-google-managed-certificates-without-downtime) for workaround helped you in overcoming the issue?

Answer (score -1):

As per Google official doc on [Move your custom domain to be served by the external Application Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless) :

> If you use Google-managed certificates, migrating an existing service to an external Application Load Balancer may incur some downtime, typically less than an hour. This is because the **SSL certificate for your external Application Load Balancer won't be provisioned until you update your DNS records to point to the load balancer’s IP address.** For more information on DNS propagation, see [Propagation of changes](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/overview#propagation_of_changes).

You can check whether DNS Mapping/propogation is completed by checking  the site [dnschecker.org](http://dnschecker.org)

As per the official GCP doc on [Map a custom domain with a global external Application Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/integrate/custom-domain-load-balancer)

> It may take up to an hour for the SSL certificate to provision and for your domain to begin routing HTTPS traffic to your Cloud Run service.

Comment: Refer to the similar [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/1084593) for workaround, which may help to resolve your issue.